# what's the difference between classpath and classpath* in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, classpath, banner

when I use spring boot banner configuration file, I find that:

## it works:

```
spring.banner.location=classpath:banner.txt
```

## not working:

```
spring.banner.location=classpath*:banner.txt
```

So what is the difference between `classpath:` and `classpath*:` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Spring documentation

> The wildcard classpath relies on the getResources() method of the underlying classloader. As most application servers nowadays supply their own classloader implementation, the behavior might differ especially when dealing with jar files. A simple test to check if classpath* works is to use the classloader to load a file from within a jar on the classpath: getClass().getClassLoader().getResources(""). Try this test with files that have the same name but are placed inside two different locations. In case an inappropriate result is returned, check the application server documentation for settings that might affect the classloader behavior.

So classPath is for load the resources from current class loader (simply for understanding will not read resources under jar or other project dependency)

classpath* will do the jar or other class loader resources.

Answer (score 1):

First since Spring boot show banner in source.You can find the code in SpringApplication.class, printBanner  method is used for to show banner.Like 
mallikarjun said classPath is for load the resources from current class loader (simply for understanding will not read resources under jar or other project dependency) classpath* will do the jar or other class loader resources.
If you use  classpath*:banner.txt will find in the jar.